# Modeling a simple Embedded System in Modelica

Tags: embedded, system, modelica

I want to model a very simple embedded system in Modelica (OpenModelica) from a more logical (or behaviour-based) point of view rather than a low-level (electrical) one. Main problem for me is, that I never worked with Modelica before and I really have troubles in grasping the idea of how to look at thinks to model them correctly.

The system should be very simply for the start and consists of a sensor which is connected via a bus with a controller. The desired behavior of the system should be, that the sensor generates values periodically and informs the controller via an interrupt. The controller in return should react to that interrupt and fetch the value. Purpose of this example for me is, as I already mentioned, to firstly grasp the idea of how to look at thinks in Modelica and to get an initial (maybe not very useful) working example that I can iteratively extend to a more complex one.

Here is the system I modeled so far:

Sensor Model:

```
model ES_Sensor
    parameter Integer id = 1;
    parameter Real frequency = 1.0;
    Integer reg_temperature = 0;
    ES_Interface interface;
algorithm
    when sample(0, 1 / frequency) then
        reg_temperature := reg_temperature + 1;
        interface.interrupt := 1;
    end when;
    when interface.address == id then
        interface.data := reg_temperature;
    end when;
end ES_Sensor;
```

Interface Connector:

```
connector ES_Interface
    flow Real dummy1;
    flow Real dummy2;
    flow Real dummy3;
    Integer address = 0;
    Integer data = 0;
    Integer interrupt = 0;
end ES_Interface;
```

Bus Model:

```
model ES_Bus
    ES_Interface master;
    ES_Interface slave;
equation
    master.data = slave.data;
    master.address = slave.address;
    master.interrupt = slave.interrupt;
end ES_Bus;
```

Controller Model:

```
 model ES_Controller
     ES_Interface interface1;
     Integer reg_a = 0;
 algorithm
     when
          interface1.interrupt == 1 then
          interface1.interrupt := 0;
          interface1.address := 1;
          reg_a := interface1.data;
          interface1.address := 0;
     end when
 end ES_Controller;
```

System Model:

```
 model Simple_System
     ES_Sensor Sensor;
     ES_Bus Bus;
 equation
     connect(Controller.interface1, Bus.master);
     connect(Bus.slave, Sensor.interface);
 end Simple_System;
```

If I try to simulate the "Simple_System" I basically get two errors. One tells me that the system is over-specified (35 equations vs. 26 variables) and the other says: "Found equation without time-dependent variables: Controller.interface1.interrupt = 0.0".

The first one I do understand, but I have absolutely now idea of how to tackle it. The second one I do not understand at all.

Any help would be appreciated! I would also be thankful if someone can at least recommend me some helpful literature.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I suggest you read a bit more about Modelica.

You can read the specification:
https://modelica.org/documents

Or read the free book by Michael T:
http://book.xogeny.com/

Or get some books by Peter F:
http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A283155%2Cp_27%3APeter%20Fritzson

As you have non physical connector you should remove the flow variables from the connector.
Also, use reinit inside when equations.

```
connector ES_Interface
    Integer address;
    Integer data;
    Integer interrupt;
end ES_Interface;

model ES_Sensor
    parameter Integer id = 1;
    parameter Real frequency = 1.0;
    Integer reg_temperature = 0;
    ES_Interface interface;
algorithm
    when sample(0, 1 / frequency) then
        reinit(reg_temperature, reg_temperature + 1);
        reinit(interface.interrupt, 1);
    end when;
    when interface.address == id then
        reinit(interface.data, reg_temperature);
    end when;
end ES_Sensor;

model ES_Bus
    ES_Interface master;
    ES_Interface slave;
equation
    master.data = slave.data;
    master.address = slave.address;
    master.interrupt = slave.interrupt;
end ES_Bus;

model ES_Controller
     ES_Interface interface1;
     Integer reg_a = 0;
 algorithm
     when interface1.interrupt == 1 then
          reinit(interface1.interrupt, 0);
          reinit(interface1.address, 1);
          reinit(reg_a, interface1.data);
     end when;
end ES_Controller;

model Simple_System
     ES_Sensor Sensor;
     ES_Bus Bus;
     ES_Controller Controller;
equation
     connect(Controller.interface1, Bus.master);
     connect(Bus.slave, Sensor.interface);
end Simple_System;
```

Now if you instantiate the model you get:

```
class Simple_System
  parameter Integer Sensor.id = 1;
  parameter Real Sensor.frequency = 1.0;
  Integer Sensor.reg_temperature = 0;
  Integer Sensor.interface.address;
  Integer Sensor.interface.data;
  Integer Sensor.interface.interrupt;
  Integer Bus.master.address;
  Integer Bus.master.data;
  Integer Bus.master.interrupt;
  Integer Bus.slave.address;
  Integer Bus.slave.data;
  Integer Bus.slave.interrupt;
  Integer Controller.interface1.address;
  Integer Controller.interface1.data;
  Integer Controller.interface1.interrupt;
  Integer Controller.reg_a = 0;
equation
  Bus.master.data = Bus.slave.data;
  Bus.master.address = Bus.slave.address;
  Bus.master.interrupt = Bus.slave.interrupt;
  Bus.master.address = Controller.interface1.address;
  Bus.master.data = Controller.interface1.data;
  Bus.master.interrupt = Controller.interface1.interrupt;
  Bus.slave.address = Sensor.interface.address;
  Bus.slave.data = Sensor.interface.data;
  Bus.slave.interrupt = Sensor.interface.interrupt;
algorithm
  when sample(0.0, 1.0 / Sensor.frequency) then
    reinit(/*Real*/(Sensor.reg_temperature), /*Real*/(1 + Sensor.reg_temperature));
    reinit(/*Real*/(Sensor.interface.interrupt), 1.0);
  end when;
  when Sensor.interface.address == Sensor.id then
    reinit(/*Real*/(Sensor.interface.data), /*Real*/(Sensor.reg_temperature));
  end when;
algorithm
  when Controller.interface1.interrupt == 1 then
    reinit(/*Real*/(Controller.interface1.interrupt), 0.0);
    reinit(/*Real*/(Controller.interface1.address), 1.0);
    reinit(/*Real*/(Controller.reg_a), /*Real*/(Controller.interface1.data));
  end when;
end Simple_System;
```

Which has 11 equations and 14 variables.
You will need more equations to model behavior of some variables.
Note that when equations are active only at a certain point in time 
so they do not count as equations. That's why you will need to add 
more equations to the model that will tell how a variable continuously
vary in time.

Comment: This is quite confusing to me. You essentially say that my model needs more equations, but the error message clearly says the opposite. Further, I can not identify those variables which are not yet described by an equation. I see that the variables "Controller.reg_a" and "Sensor.reg_temperature" are missing in the equation section, but according to my understanding are those variables "discrete", since they are of type Integer and so they keep their values constant between events. Could you please give me an example of what equations I could add to the model?